# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application (didnt find class)

Tags: flutter

[image: Error report image]

#java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.MrMaterial.MainActivity:#

> this report came as a lab test result

> I read some of this similar question, but I haven't get correct answer

> full report below here

> I thick some mistakes are in android mainfestAtivity

Answer (score 0):

I see there is a difference between the package names mentioned `com.Men.MainActivity` and `com.MrMaterial.MainActivity`.

Check the proper package name.

Comment: it was typing mistake when I asked question here, package name are same in the code